# Casting of primitives type

Tags: java

I am beginner in Java. I cannot understand this line even after a long try.

byte num=(byte)135;

this line gives result -121 why it is in signed  number ?

Can any one elaborate it ?

Comment: Look up twos-complement representation. Basically, 135 is too big to fit into a byte, and it looks like a negative number when truncated to fit

Comment: Because `byte` is an 8-bit signed value, and has a range of -128 to 127.  Look at the bit pattern for 135 (hint: Windows Calculator will convert between decimal, octal, binary and hex) and figure out what it would mean as an 8-bit signed value.

Answer (score 8):

In Java, `byte`s are always signed, and they are in the range `-128` to `127`.  When the `int` literal `135` is downcasted to a `byte`, the result is a negative number because the 8th bit is set.

```
 1000 0111
```

Specifically, the [JLS, Section 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), states:

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

When you cast an `int` literal such as `135` to a `byte`, that is a narrowing primitive conversion.